# Setting CORS to incoming request IP

Tags: browser, ibmhttpserver

I am using IBM HTTP Server 9.0.0.7.
There is a planned integration in which the user is setting request via chrome.
httpd.conf contains the following

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 SSLEnable
 Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, 
 Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Credentials"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
</VirtualHost>
```

The browser allows the initial login request but on subsequent ajax requests are blocked by CORS
The error thrown is

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://someip/api?select=category,description' from origin 'http://localhost:38359' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. 
The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Since the integration is browser based. i.e the user will be accessing the API via browser. I think the solution is to set `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the incoming request IP.

Any idea how this can be done.
btw I have no control over this integration other than I can change the HTTP server settings.

Answer (score 1):

It wants the origin initiating the XHR request, which is in the error message: http://localhost:38359

If you need to support multiple origins without * (due to the use of credentials) you will need to make it conditional on the Origin: header coming in as input.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(localhost:38359)$" ACAO=$0
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(some-other-origin-allowed)$" ACAO=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ACAO}e env=ACAO
```